# XML to Word Table

Tags: c#, xml, ms-word

I am trying to create a word table from xml file but the rows are not in their proper order,ie the first element occurs as last row, 2nd as 1st row and so on. Where am i going wrong?

```
Word.Table oTable;
Word.Range wrdRng = oDoc.Bookmarks.get_Item(ref oEndOfDoc).Range;
oTable = oDoc.Tables.Add(wrdRng, ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count, ds.Tables[0].Columns.Count, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
oTable.Range.ParagraphFormat.SpaceAfter = 6;
oTable.Borders.InsideLineStyle = Word.WdLineStyle.wdLineStyleSingle;
oTable.Borders.OutsideLineStyle = Word.WdLineStyle.wdLineStyleSingle;
for (int r = 1; r <= ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; r++)
{
    for (int c = 1; c <= ds.Tables[0].Columns.Count; c++)
    {
        oTable.Cell(r, c).Range.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[r-1].ItemArray[c-1].ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample code to create simple word file with Table. It will give you a loop hint how to proceed with it.

```
class Program
{
    static void  Main(string[] args)

    {
        Document doc = new Document();
        Section s = doc.AddSection();
        Table table = s.AddTable(true);

        //Create Header and Data
        String[] header = { "Item", "Description", "Qty", "Unit Price", "Price" };
        String[][] data = {
                              new String[]{ "Spire.Doc for .NET",".NET Word Component","1","$799.00","$799.00"},
                              new String[]{"Spire.XLS for .NET",".NET Excel Component","2","$799.00","$1,598.00"},
                              new String[]{"Spire.Office for .NET",".NET Office Component","1","$1,899.00","$1,899.00"},
                              new String[]{"Spire.PDF for .NET",".NET PDFComponent","2","$599.00","$1,198.00"},
                          };
        //Add Cells
        table.ResetCells(data.Length + 1, header.Length);

        //Header Row
        TableRow fRow = table.Rows[0];
        fRow.IsHeader = true;
        //Row Height
        fRow.Height = 23;
        //Header Format
        fRow.RowFormat.BackColor = Color.AliceBlue;
        for (int i = 0; i < header.Length; i++)
        {
            //Cell Alignment
            Paragraph p = fRow.Cells[i].AddParagraph();
            fRow.Cells[i].CellFormat.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Middle;
            p.Format.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
            //Data Format
            TextRange TR = p.AppendText(header[i]);
            TR.CharacterFormat.FontName = "Calibri";
            TR.CharacterFormat.FontSize = 14;
            TR.CharacterFormat.TextColor = Color.Teal;
            TR.CharacterFormat.Bold = true;
        }

        //Data Row
        for (int r = 0; r < data.Length; r++)
        {
            TableRow dataRow = table.Rows[r + 1];

            //Row Height
            dataRow.Height = 20;

            //C Represents Column.
            for (int c = 0; c < data[r].Length; c++)
            {
                //Cell Alignment
                dataRow.Cells[c].CellFormat.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Middle;
                //Fill Data in Rows
                Paragraph p2 = dataRow.Cells[c].AddParagraph();
                TextRange TR2 = p2.AppendText(data[r][c]);
                //Format Cells
                p2.Format.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
                TR2.CharacterFormat.FontName = "Calibri";
                TR2.CharacterFormat.FontSize = 12;
                TR2.CharacterFormat.TextColor = Color.Brown;
            }
        }

        //Save and Launch
        doc.SaveToFile("WordTable.docx", FileFormat.Docx2013);
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("WordTable.docx");


        Console.ReadLine();

    }
```